# XmlDomParserContext.java:94:in `<init>': java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class nokogiri.internals.NokogiriHelpers

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, jruby, nokogiri, jrubyonrails

I am working on a jruby project, I am getting some XML PARSING error related to Nokogiri whose console log is as shown below :

```
> XmlDomParserContext.java:94:in `<init>':
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
> nokogiri.internals.NokogiriHelpers
>         from XmlDocument.java:317:in `newFromData'
>         from XmlDocument.java:334:in `read_memory'
>         from XmlDocument$INVOKER$s$0$0$read_memory.gen:-1:in `call'
>         from CachingCallSite.java:70:in `call'
>         from FCallManyArgsNode.java:60:in `interpret'
>         from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
>         from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
>         from IfNode.java:118:in `interpret'
>         from LocalAsgnNode.java:123:in `interpret'
>         from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
>         from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
>         from ASTInterpreter.java:75:in `INTERPRET_METHOD'
>         from InterpretedMethod.java:112:in `call'
>         from DefaultMethod.java:158:in `call'
>         from CachingCallSite.java:79:in `callBlock'
>         from CachingCallSite.java:85:in `call'
>         from CallManyArgsBlockPassNode.java:57:in `interpret'
>         from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
>         from ASTInterpreter.java:75:in `INTERPRET_METHOD'
>         from InterpretedMethod.java:182:in `call'
>         from DefaultMethod.java:192:in `call'
>         from CachingCallSite.java:326:in `cacheAndCall'
>         from CachingCallSite.java:170:in `call'
>         from CallOneArgNode.java:57:in `interpret'
>         from DAsgnNode.java:110:in `interpret'
>         from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
>         from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
>         from RescueNode.java:226:in `executeBody'
>         from RescueNode.java:123:in `interpretWithJavaExceptions'
>         from RescueNode.java:113:in `interpret'
>         from BeginNode.java:83:in `interpret'
>         from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
>         from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
>         from ASTInterpreter.java:112:in `INTERPRET_BLOCK'
>         from Interpreted19Block.java:209:in `evalBlockBody'
>         from Interpreted19Block.java:197:in `yield'
>         from Interpreted19Block.java:128:in `call'
>         from Block.java:89:in `call'
>         from RubyProc.java:261:in `call'
>         from RubyProc.java:213:in `call'
>         from Ruby.java:2873:in `tearDown'
>         from Ruby.java:2857:in `tearDown'
>         from Main.java:267:in `internalRun'
>         from Main.java:230:in `run'
>         from Main.java:214:in `run'
>         from Main.java:194:in `main'
```

jruby version is [jruby 1.7.0.RC1 (1.9.3p203) 2012-09-25 8e849de on Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 1.6.0_37-b06 [Windows XP-x86]]

OS : Windows XP

Java version :
java version "1.6.0_37"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_37-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.12-b01, mixed mode, sharing)

Does anyone have any idea about this issue ?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using 1.7.0 final?

Comment: What version of Nokogiri are you using? `nokogiri -v` should give you all the information you need to report bugs to nokogiri-talk ...

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the class `nokogiri.internals.NokogiriHelpers` has an static initialization block that threw an exception, but the exception was somehow suppressed.

Try putting the `static` block in a `try`-`catch` and log any exceptions to find out.

```
class NokogiriHelpers {
    static {
         try { 
             // your initialization stuff
         } catch (Exception e) {
             // log e
         }
    } 
}
```

Note that any static constants you may have defined in `NokogiriHelpers` also has an static initializer, so you may want to put them in try catch too. If you have

```
class NokogiriHelpers {
    static int FOO = computeFoo();
}
```

and `computeFoo()` may throw an unchecked exception, you have to change it to

```
class NokogiriHelpers {
    static int FOO;
    static {
         try { 
             FOO = computeFoo();
         } catch (Exception e) {
             // log e
         }
    } 
}
```